# Creating Subfolders within Named Folders

Tags: batch-file, make, files-folders

Kevin Fegan posted the following code to make "x" amount of folders with leading zeros, which works great:

```
@echo off
for /L %%f in (9,1,120) do call :work 000%%f
goto :EOF
:work
set "dx=%~1"
set "dx=%dx:~-3%"
md "C:\Dropbox\Development\Lec-%dx%" >nul 2>&1
set "dx="
goto :EOF
```

I need to also make 3 subfolders under the lecture folders named Request, Response and Support.  I tried the following but I just get the folder Request under each of the Lec-XXX folders.

```
md "C:\Dropbox\Development\Lec-%dx%"***\Request Response Support*** >nul 2>&1
```

I feel like I am missing something mundane but cannot figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is this part  : `***\Request Response Support***`?

Comment: That is where i am trying to create the three subfolders under each named folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off 

cd /d "C:\Dropbox\Development"

for /L %%L in (9,1,120)do set "_folder=000%%~L" && (
   cmd /v:on /c "mkdir "%cd%\Lec-!_folder:~-3!"" & (
           for %%i in (Request,Response,Support)do (
   cmd /v:on /c "mkdir "%cd%\Lec-!_folder:~-3!\%%i""
   ))) 2>nul
```

---

You can use one addition `for` loop and using `!EnableDelayedExpansion!` with `cmd /v`
for create your folder:

```
cmd /v:on /c "mkdir "%cd%\Lec-!_folder:~-3!"" & (
        for %%i in (Request,Response,Support)do (
cmd /v:on /c "mkdir "%cd%\Lec-!_folder:~-3!\%%i""
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Cmd /?](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**

  [√] **[For /L /?](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)**

  [√] **[For /L /?](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)**

  [√] **[Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  [√] **[`EnableDelayedExpansion` | Refer: `cmd /v:on`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)**

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in my response.  I finally got around to inputting your code and it works perfectly!  Thank you so much as this will save me hours every year.  Cheers!